# Como paginar um foreach de um file_get_contents?

Tags: php, loop, foreach, paginação

Estou consultando uma API que me fornece dados formatados em JSON, faço a coleta através do file_get_contents e depois imprimo todos os valores utilizando um foreach. Porem são muitos valores, mais de 5.000 itens, preciso pagina-los, tentei limita-los usando um array_slice porem não consigo exibir o restante dos valores ao mudar o numero das páginas.

Estou usando o seguinte código para coleta dos dados:

```
$url            = 'URL_DA_API';
$servers_zip    = file_get_contents($url);
$servers_raw    = gzdecode($servers_zip);
$json           = json_decode($servers_raw, true);
```

Para criar o loop uso o seguinte:

```
foreach (array_slice($json['GET'], 0, 50) as $index=>$sv)
```

Por fim minha paginação está assim:

```
function paginacao($quantreg,$numreg,$url){
        global $paginas;
        global $pg;
        $quant_pg = ceil($quantreg/$numreg);
        $quant_pg++;

        // Verifica se esta na primeira página, se nao estiver ele libera o link para anterior
        if ($pg > 0) { 
            echo '<li class="prev"><a href="'.$url.'&pg='.($pg-1).'">Anterior</a></li>';
        } 

        // Faz aparecer os numeros das página entre o ANTERIOR e PROXIMO
        for($i_pg=1;$i_pg<$quant_pg;$i_pg++) { 
                // Verifica se a página que o navegante esta e retira o link do número para identificar visualmente
                if ($pg == ($i_pg-1)) { 
                        echo '<li class="active">'.$i_pg.'</li>';
                } else {
                        $i_pg2 = $i_pg-1;
                        echo '<li><a href="'.$url.'&pg='.$i_pg2.'">'.$i_pg.'</a></li>';
                }
        }

        // Verifica se esta na ultima página, se nao estiver ele libera o link para próxima
        if (($pg+2) < $quant_pg) { 
                echo '<li class="next"><a href="'.$url.'&pg='.($pg+1).'">Próximo</a></li>';
        }
}
```

A primeira página está exibindo tudo perfeito, numero de itens, números de paginas, ao clicar em um numero "página 58" ele retorna a url da página 58 porem com os valores da página 1. :(

Alguém me ajuda?

Answer (score -1):

Você precisa paginar os dados no array_slice. Considerando que a primeira página tem indice zero, ficaria mais ou menos assim:

```
foreach (array_slice($json['GET'], $pag * $reg_por_pag, $reg_por_pag) as $index=>$sv)
```

Comment: Não funcionou Júlio, me confirma quais valores irão em 
$pag * $reg_por_pag, $reg_por_pag

Comment: Em $pag deve ir o número da página, começando por zero, em $reg_per_page o número de registros em cada página. Isso se eu entendi bem a forma q vc esta fazendo.

Comment: É isso mesmo, deu certo. Notei que o erro não estava nos valores que eu estava inserindo, e sim no no identificador de item da array. Tentei indexa-los através do $index, porem quando troco de página o $index zera novamente. Como eu poderia indexar esses resultados?